# How to display puzzle pieces within the UI panel upon the initial generation

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ui

[image: How to make the first puzzle piece appear in the panel]

```cs
public class Piecespawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Referensi ke objek skripable PieceList yang berisi daftar potongan puzzle
    public PieceList pieceList

    // Tingkat di mana potongan-potongan akan muncul (potongan per detik)
    public float spawnRate = 1f;

    // Array dari titik spawn di mana potongan-potongan akan diciptakan
    public GameObject[] spawnPoints;

    // List untuk melacak potongan aktif dalam adegan
    private List<GameObject> activePieces = new List<GameObject>();

    // Start dipanggil sebelum frame pertama
    void Start()
    {
        // Mulai coroutine untuk terus-menerus menciptakan potongan
        StartCoroutine(SpawnPiece());
    }

    // Coroutine untuk menciptakan potongan puzzle
    IEnumerator SpawnPiece()
    {
        // Terus-menerus menciptakan potongan tanpa batas
        while (true)
        {
            // Hentikan menciptakan jika semua titik spawn sudah terisi
            if (activePieces.Count >= spawnPoints.Length)
            {
                yield return null;
                continue;
            }

            // Pilih secara acak potongan puzzle dari daftar
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, pieceList.Piecepuzzle.Count);
            GameObject selectedPiece = pieceList.Piecepuzzle[randomIndex].shapeTriangle;

            // Bangkitkan indeks titik spawn acak, pastikan tidak ada yang sudah terisi
            int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);
            while (activePieces.Exists(piece => piece.transform.localPosition == spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].transform.localPosition))
            {
                spawnPointIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);
            }

            // Ciptakan potongan yang dipilih di titik spawn yang dipilih
            GameObject spawnedPiece = Instantiate(selectedPiece, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].transform.localPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            activePieces.Add(spawnedPiece);

            // Tunggu sejumlah waktu tertentu sebelum mencoba menciptakan potongan lainnya
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnRate);
        }
    }

    // OnDestroy dipanggil ketika instance skrip dihancurkan
    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // Hancurkan semua potongan aktif saat skrip dihancurkan
        foreach (GameObject piece in activePieces)
        {
            Destroy(piece);
        }
    }
}
```